# OpenVPN AS split tunneling with "whitelisted" domains

Tags: vpn, openvpn, split-dns, split-tunnel

got a requirement to enable split tunneling for our work openVPN as server's

This also includes having a "split DNS" configuration where some internal/public company domains traffic should go through the VPN server

e.g company domain is `example.com` and `xyz.example.com` traffic should go through the VPN

Whats not working ?

seems like the traffic still goes through my local network rather then VPN network even it's whitelisted

Confirmed it by using `traceroute` / visiting https://whatismyipaddress.com (when it's whitelisted)

My setup

(local)

- MacOS Ventura 13.0
- OpenVPN client `v3.4.1`

(remote)

- EC2 Instance (`ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20230207` AMI)
- OpenVPN access server `v2.12.3`

my config so far

Routing

[image]

DNS settings

[image]

Comment: You should specify the client platforms tested due to some platforms perform DNS queries in parallel against all servers by default. https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-dns-resolution-problems/

Comment: @GregAskew added

Comment: @GregAskew any change you have an idea ?

Comment: shouldn't the "DNS resolution zones" contain instead: "example.com" (and only that) ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac I don't think so, as you can see at screenshot "specify a comma-separated list of internal ..."

Answer (score 0):

You write that your setup requires split DNS, which means that when connected to your VPN, the hostname `xyz.example.com` should resolve to an internal IP which is included inside your VPN configuration. For this to work, you must have a special DNS server, which is reachable through your VPN, and that DNS server must be pushed to all your clients connecting.
Here are the steps required to pinpoint the problem:

- while connected to your VPN, execute `ping xyz.example.com` to see if:

  1. the hostname resolves to the *internal* IP address
  2. the ping works and the server is actually reachable - to test if the internal IP address is included in the VPN definition. Don't forget to ping the internal IP address manually, if the DNS resolution is not working - you also must make sure that the VPN is working as intended!
- if the hostname does not resolve to the internal IP address, execute `host xyz.example.de 1.2.3.4` where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of your internal DNS server.

Depending on the outcome of this command:

- if the above command does not resolve this name to the internal IP, check the configuration of your internal DNS server.
- if the host command gives a timeout, you probably need to include the DNS IP inside your VPN definition.
- if the command correctly returns the internal IP address, you need to check your VPN configuration to ensure that the internal DNS server is pushed to the client and actually replaces the one your client has been using! (check `/etc/resolv.conf` on your mac!)

I am pretty sure you will find the issue with these steps.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks !